# starting and stopping a daemon at user login logout

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, kde-plasma, daemons

I have a daemon script written in ruby which responds to commands like `daemon start` and `daemon stop`. It's executable with shebang `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and it works invoked from terminal. I need to start the daemon on login and stop it on logout.

Background info: KDE, zsh.

I already tried to make two separate shell scripts with `daemon start` and `daemon stop` and place them in `~/.kde4/Autostart` | `~/.kde4/shutdown`. The scripts `start.sh` and `stop.sh` are working in terminal, but no luck in autostart or shutdown.

I can't put them in `.zshrc` respectively `.zlogout`, because I start many login shells in a work session.

So I am stuck :) Any ideas?

**Update:** <kbd>F1</kbd> => Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running the program as an [autostart](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) app, and then have it watch to see when its parent (probably the session manager) stops running.

Comment: Unfortunately  `The desktop environment MAY ignore Autostart files altogether based on policy set by the user, system administrator or vendor.` citing from provided link, this makes me to don't accept your answer as reliable.

Comment: You can either play nice, or you can have people roll their eyes because of the experiences they've had in getting their systems hijacked in all the wrong places.

Comment: I agree with you, but as I wrote in question sort of `autostart` app does not work on kde. We are talking about [this application](http://github.com/kfl62/MPD-DBus-Kopete) which is KDE specific and I wish to complete installation instructions with an response posted here (if any). I don't think that providing reliable install/use instructions means hijacking.