# Python script as daemon in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, daemon

I created a daemon to run a python script. but it stops whenever i logout from my ubuntu machine.

```
DAEMON=sudo python /var/www/some_dir/my_python.py
ARGS=/var/www/some_dir/my_python.py
PIDFILE=/var/www/some_dir/my_python.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

#set -e

case "$1" in
start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON &
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIFDILE --exec $DAEMON
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
restart|force-reload)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
    sleep 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON &
    echo "$NAME."
    ;;
*)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

can anyone tell me how can i do it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
[starting and stopping a daemon at user login logout][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950585/starting-and-stopping-a-daemon-at-user-login-logout

Comment: i use "sudo /etc/init.d/my_python start"

Comment: I would have thought `start-stop-daemon` takes care of everything... obviously it does not. Try trapping the `SIGHUP` signal in the Python script. Redirecting the output to a file or `/dev/null` may also be wise.

Comment: i have tried that too. it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

It's a long time since this question was asked, but I came across this situation today.

To start the process in the background, use

```
start-stop-daemon -Sbm --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
```

To stop it:

```
start-stop-daemon -K --pidfile $PIDFILE
```

From the [start-stop-daemon man page](http://www.calculate-linux.org/main/en/start-stop-daemon):

> -b , -background
>
> Force the daemon into the background. Some daemons don't create
>   pidfiles, so a good trick is to get the daemon to run in the
>   foreground, and use the this option along with -m , -make-pidfile to
>   create a working pidfile.
>   -m , -make-pidfile
>
> Saves the pid of the daemon in the file specified by the -p, -pidfile
>   option. Only useful when used with daemons that run in the foreground
>   and forced into the background with the --b, -background option.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `&` from your `start-stop-daemon` invocations. Also, you should read how to write proer initscripts because there are several other errors in your initscript.

Comment: the daemon still stops after i logout.

Comment: wRAR is there any other way to run python script in background ?

Comment: `screen`, `nohup`, `&` + `disown` etc. Anyway, the only proper way is to write a script properly as daemon and write a proper initscript.